# Couldn't get application list from specified server?

Tags: android, ibm-datacap

I installed IBM Datacap Mobile(http://bit.ly/1MohH4Q) android application.The datacap version for this application is 9.0.0.2 .I get "Couldn't get application list from specified server.The server might not be accessiable." I specify the correct datacap access url in following format. http://host:port.But I am getting above mentioned error.What is the cause for this problem? Is any specific configuration settings for datacap 9.0.0.2?

Please suggest me on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from the [knowledge center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZRWV_9.0.0/com.ibm.dc.admin.doc/dcaad054.htm), you need to install the Datacap Web Services interface, and then provide the URL for that interface in the app.

Steps to install the Web Services can be found [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZRWV_9.0.0/com.ibm.dc.install.doc/dcitws001.htm).

Comment: Thanks.Actually I am using IBM Datacap Mobile.This is an android application and version is 9.0.0.2.I installed this application.here I see only one field called Datacap Server URL. Here I enter datacap url like http://host:port/  .I press connect button.But it shows above mentioned error.So please suggest.

Comment: You're trying to connect to a Datacap server... did you install the web services interface on the server? They are needed by the application to be able to connect.